# Android Studio App Crash Databases App Crash Wrong

Tags: android, sqlite, crash

2022-02-26 00:24:09.641 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteAssetHelper: Couldn't open EatItDB.db for writing (will try read-only):
com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/EatItDB.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:875)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:852)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:436)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)
at com.example.kampusegel1.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:55)
at com.example.kampusegel1.FoodDetail$1.onClick(FoodDetail.java:58)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 W/SQLiteLog: (28) failed to open "/data/user/0/com.example.kampusegel1/databases/EatItDB.db" with flag (131072) and mode_t (0) due to error (2)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 37805 of [68b898381a]
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:37805: (2) open(/data/user/0/com.example.kampusegel1/databases/EatItDB.db) -
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteLog: (1) Process ple.kampusegel1 : Pid (32217) Uid (10420) Euid (10420) Gid (10420) Egid (10420)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteLog: (1) osStat failed "/data/user/0/com.example.kampusegel1/databases/EatItDB.db" due to error (2)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/user/0/com.example.kampusegel1/databases : st_mode(40771) st_uid(10420) st_gid(10420) st_ino(3678242)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/user/0/com.example.kampusegel1 : st_mode(40700) st_uid(10420) st_gid(10420) st_ino(3678239)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/user/0 : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(3473409)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/user : st_mode(40711) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(2555905)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.644 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(2)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.646 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.example.kampusegel1/databases/EatItDB.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1294 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT[1294]): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:300)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:737)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:284)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:251)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1386)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:994)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:940)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
at com.example.kampusegel1.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:55)
at com.example.kampusegel1.FoodDetail$1.onClick(FoodDetail.java:58)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
2022-02-26 00:24:09.646 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-02-26 00:24:09.647 32217-32217/com.example.kampusegel1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.kampusegel1, PID: 32217
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1294 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT[1294]): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:300)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:737)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:284)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:251)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1386)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:994)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:940)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
at com.example.kampusegel1.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:55)
at com.example.kampusegel1.FoodDetail$1.onClick(FoodDetail.java:58)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)

This is how the app crashes when I click the button.
I created the assets/databases folder.
I also deleted the cache files, but my problem is still not resolved.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Is there an updated version?

Uninstalled and re-run, if passed, it must be no update, the version of the data

From China, English is not good